# Angular mat-table, Transform each element of a list-like to a row

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

I am new to Angular/Javascript and currently using AngularJS to represent table which has following data / code

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="columnA">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>A</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.columnA}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="columnB">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>B</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.columnB}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="columnC">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>C</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.columnC}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

for js,

```
displayedColumns = ['columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC'];
export interface exampleColumns{
    columnA: string[];
    columnB: number[];
    columnC: string;
}
const EXAMPLE_DATA: exampleColumns[] = [
    {
        columnA: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        columnB: [1, 2, 3],
        columnC: 'apple'

    },
    {
        columnA: ['D', 'E'],
        columnB: [4, 5],
        columnC: 'banana'
    },
    {
        columnA: ['F'],
        columnB: [6],
        columnC: 'orange'

    }
]
dataSource = EXAMPLE_DATA
```

which would render following table.

```
| A | B | C |
|---|---|---|
| ['A', 'B', 'C'] | [1, 2, 3]  | 'apple'  |
| ['D', 'E'] | [4, 5]  | 'banana'  |
| ['F']  | [6]  |  'orange' |
```

But what I want is to transform each element of a list-like to a row, (there is a similar concept in [pandas.Dataframe.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), multi-column explode case) as following

```
| A | B | C |
|---|---|---|
| 'A'  | 1  | 'apple'  |
| 'B'  | 2  | 'apple'  |
| 'C'  | 3  | 'apple'  |
| 'D'  | 4  | 'banana'  |
| 'E'  | 5  | 'banana'  |
| 'F'  | 6  | 'orange'  |
```

My initial idea was to play with `*ngFor` in `ng-container` to iterate columnA or columnB which turned out to be not working.

I would be grateful if someone has a better idea :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a function which will explode all the columns

```
function covertToRows(obj) {
    const array = [];
    const maxArraySize = Math.max(...Object.values(obj).filter((val) => Array.isArray(val)).map(arr => arr.length));
    for (let i = 0; i < maxArraySize; i++) {
        const columnA = Array.isArray(obj.columnA) ? obj.columnA[i] ?? '' : obj.columnA;
        const columnB = Array.isArray(obj.columnB) ? obj.columnB[i] ?? '' : obj.columnB;
        const columnC = Array.isArray(obj.columnC) ? obj.columnC[i] ?? '' : obj.columnC;
        array.push({
            columnA,
            columnB,
            columnC
        });
    }
    return array;
}
```

Maybe you expect a `NaN` for number type column, you can replace `''` with `NaN`.

You can checkout `d3` library, it's used for data visualizations, maybe it serves your purpose for data manipulation.